# How to create directory structure with identical metadata/timestamps on consecutive runs using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, directory, timestamp, metadata

```
$ install -m755 -d "/tmp/usr/lib/modules/4.14.4-1-ARCH/kernel"
```

creates multiple new directory entries inside a bash script that creates a Linux initramfs file. For the file/folder metadata to be consistent between runs, the idea is to reference the folder timestamps to the kernel itself, with `touch --reference=<source_file> <new_created_directory>`.

The individually to be touched folders can be retrieved via `install --verbose` command, like:

```
$ install -v -m755 -d "/tmp/usr/lib/modules/4.14.4-1-ARCH/kernel"
install: creating directory '/tmp/usr'
install: creating directory '/tmp/usr/lib'
install: creating directory '/tmp/usr/lib/modules'
install: creating directory '/tmp/usr/lib/modules/4.14.4-1-ARCH'
install: creating directory '/tmp/usr/lib/modules/4.14.4-1-ARCH/kernel'
```

#### Directions

1. redirect output of file descriptor #1 to an array, and loop through the array. Maybe the array is not even nessary and the `install -v -d` output can be immediately piped into a readline type of code block.
2. directory traversal from the created directory up till root of temporary initramfs, `/tmp` in the example above.

How to create a **directory structure** with identical metadata on consecutive runs? For example the necessary touch command loop and parameter expansions (PE) to match the newly created directories by **`install`**?

---

> The parent bash script is writing a skeleton minimal Linux file and folder
>   structure to a temporary location, that will finally be compressed
>   into an initramfs structure. The goal is to be able to recreate binary
>   identical initramfs files on consecutive script runs. By default the files are
>   identical, but the metadata is not due to different creation/access
>   timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the directory structure is ready to create the `initramfs` based on it,
set the timestamp of all files and directories to a reference point.
You can use the `find` command for this:

```
find path/to/basedir -exec touch -r "$reference_file" {} +
```

If you want to touch only files that were created by `install` commands,
than you can create a marker file that you can use with the `-newer` predicate of `find`, for example:

```
marker=/tmp/marker
touch "$marker"
install ...

find path/to/basedir -newer "$marker" -exec touch -r "$reference_file" {} +
```

If you want touch specifically the files printed by `install -v -d ...`,
where all the output lines are expected to have this format:

> ```
> install: creating directory '...'
> ```

Then you could pipe the output of `install` to a loop that reads line by line,
and extracts the paths by chopping the prefix of the line until the first `'`,
and chopping off everything from the last `'`:

```
... | while read -r line; do
    [[ $line = *'install: creating directory '* ]] || continue
    line=${line#*\'}
    line=${line%\'*}
    touch -r "$reference_file" "$line"
done
```

Comment: This find /path/to/basedir solution touches everything. I do only want to touch the newly created directories, in the example the 5 created directories. I don't want to touch any other file/directory.

Comment: @ProBackup by `path/to/basedir` I mean the directory that contains everything that has to go into the `initramfs`. All those files should be touched to make the `initramfs` binary equivalent every time. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ProBackup In any case, I added to my answer something that might help.

Comment: The `find -newer "$marker"` is a clever idea. Though it doesn't look efficient: scanning the whole directory tree and all files for timestamps, while the `install -v` output already contains the directories to touch.

Comment: @ProBackup I think that parsing the output of `install -v` would not be robust. I think the performance concern for scanning the while directory tree is not significant, because I expect the tree of `initramfs` files to be small.

Comment: I agree with the non robustness to parse `install -v` output. One can never be sure if the directory tree is small or large. A directory walk from the deepest created directory up till tmp initramfs root will do the job more efficient.

Comment: @ProBackup Glad you agree. For your information, I added an alternative approach based on the output of `install -v`.

Comment: I think the robustness will improve with an additional line check: `if [[ $line = *'install: creating directory '* ]]; then # start line processing`. Would you mind if I edit this in your answer?

Comment: @ProBackup not a bad idea, I added it myself ;-)